# Unable to add video in my website

Tags: javascript

Some problem with the width and height, it shows up on the full page . Also my video is working on firefox but not on chrome

```
<div id="videoTop" style="position:fixed;  right: 0px; min-width: 100%; min-height: 50%; width: auto; height: auto; z-index: 1; overflow:hidden;">

    <script>
        if (jQuery.browser.mobile) {
            $('div#videoTop').remove();
        }
        else { }
    </script>

    <video id="videoBG" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0" tabindex="0" style="position: fixed;  right: 0px; min-width: 100%; min-height: 30%; width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -2; overflow: hidden;">
        <source src="Images/Wildlife.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;">
        <source src="/assets/1550/allure-homepage.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;">
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If == true you're removing the whole block of markup you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code will remove the entire block when true since there's only 1 `<div>` tag. Is that what you want, and is mobile browsers where you're encountering the error?

For non-mobile browsers, try removing the codecs, which aren't usually necessary & which appear to include unnecessary quotation marks and semi-colons that are breaking your code above.

```
 <video id="videoBG" preload="auto" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0" tabindex="0" style="position: fixed; right: 0px; min-width: 100%; min-height: 30%; width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -2; overflow: hidden;">
     <source src="Images/Wildlife.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="/assets/1550/allure-homepage.webm" type="video/webm">
 </video>
```

If not that, confirm your file paths to the videos. Why are they totally different videos and different subfolders ("Images" vs "assets") for different browsers?
Finally, is there other content? Why z-index of -2? Could something else be covering the video?

Comment: Well that source "assets/1550.." is not supposed to be there. rather same file with .ogg format. Yes, The video should be hidden behind the other div tags which includes the content and when scrolled down, thats when video should appear.

Comment: That may be your problem then ;)